# Магический квадрат

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Есть целая квадратная матрица. Нужно определить является ли эта матрица магическим квадратом, т.е. такой матрицой в которой суммы элементов во всех строках и столбцах одинаковы.

Мой код:

```
import random
p=0
n=int(input('Введите четное число: '))
matrix=[[random.randrange(10) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for elem in matrix:
    print(elem)
for k in range(n):    #Проверяю равны ли суммы всех элементов строк между собой
    for l in range(k+1,n):
         if sum(matrix[k])==sum(matrix[l]):
            p+=1    #если предыдущая строка равна по сумме элементов следущей, то переменную p увеличиваю на единицу, чтобы потом если p==n (если p равняется кол-ву строк, то потом проверять на сумму элементов по столбцам матрицы)
```

Но как проверить равны ли суммы элементов столбцов матрицы? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: В [магическом квадрате](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82) также должна совпадать сумма главной и побочной диагоналей ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Нет нужды сравнивать все строки со всеми, чтобы выяснить, что все суммы равны. Достаточно найти первую сумму и сравнивать остальные с ней.

```
first = sum(matrix[0])
for k in range(1, n):
    if sum(matrix[0]) != first:
        return False
```

Для столбцов - просто посчитать их суммы и так же сравнить с эталоном

```
for k in range(0, n):
    if sum([row[k] for row in matrix]) != first:
        return False
```

Comment: для столбцов я же могу проверить суммы таким образом?: for q in range(n):
  for w in range(q+1,n):
   if sum([x[q] for x in matrix])==sum([y[w] for y in matrix]):
    h+=1

Comment: Да, можно - но опять же -  не нужно все столбцы попарно сравнивать

Answer (score 10):

Я бы, наверное, сделал так:

```
import numpy as np

def ismagic(a):
    if np.array_equal(np.unique(a.sum(axis=1)),np.unique(a.sum(axis=0))):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Проверяем:

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [4, 3]])
print(ismagic(a))
b = np.ones((5,5))
print(ismagic(b))
c = np.matrix([[2,7,6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8]])
print(ismagic(c))
d = np.matrix([[17,24,1,8,15],[23,5,7,14,16],[4,6,13,20,22],[10,12,19,21,3],[11,18,25,2,9]])
print(ismagic(d))
```

На выходе:

```
False
True
True
True
```

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, сначала вставил неверную строчку из ноутбука, когда код копировал. Сейчас исправил. Насчет возврата значений - согласен. Обновил код.

Answer (score 5):

Решение с использованием модуля Numpy для проверки на [настоящий магический квадрат (с проверкой сумм главной и побочной диагоналей)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,7,6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8]])
```

---

```
In [90]: a
Out[90]:
array([[2, 7, 6],
       [9, 5, 1],
       [4, 3, 8]])

In [91]: a.sum(axis=0)
Out[91]: array([15, 15, 15])

In [92]: a.sum(axis=1)
Out[92]: array([15, 15, 15])

In [93]: np.diag(a).sum()
Out[93]: 15

In [94]: np.diag(np.flipr(a)).sum()
Out[94]: 15
```

---

решение:

```
In [98]: s = np.diag(a).sum()

In [99]: (s == np.diag(np.flipr(a)).sum()) and (a.sum(axis=0) == s).all() and (a.sum(axis=1) == s).all()
Out[99]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: matrix = [
    ...: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ...: [8, 9, 5, 4, 5],
    ...: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5],
    ...: [7, 8, 9, 4, 2]
    ...: ]

In [14]: main_sum = sum(matrix[0]) * 2

In [15]: def foo(matrix):
    ...:     tran = np.array(matrix).T
    ...:     for i, j in zip(matrix, tran):
    ...:         if sum(i) + sum(j) != main_sum:
    ...:             return False
    ...:     return True
    ...:
    ...:

In [16]: foo(matrix)
Out[16]: False

In [17]: matrix = [[2, 7, 6], [9, 5, 1], [4, 3, 8]] # magic

In [18]: foo(matrix)
Out[18]: True
```

> Работает на матрицах где кол-во строк равно кол-ву столбцов.

Comment: Функция foo(matrix) вообще нельзя применить, потому что в ней используется внешняя переменная main_sum, которую неизвестно где брать.

Comment: @Эникейщик простите, что?

Comment: Да вроде бы ясно написано, что. Функция foo() - нерабочая.

Comment: @Эникейщик вполне себе рабочая.

Comment: Скопируйте в отдельный файл и запустите. Она рабочая потому что main_sum определена выше, уберите ту строчку и вся рабочесть закончится ошибкой.

Comment: @Эникейщик эм, мне не определять переменные "выше"? Я непонимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: Да я уже два раза написал в чем проблема. Скопируйте функцию в отдельный файл, запустите и увидите в чем проблема.